# I can't get SqlDependency to fire, am I doing something obviously wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to setup a `SqlDependency` so my Winforms app doesn't have to bog down the server with 1 second repeating select queries to find out if a table value has changed. I have gotten rid of all the exceptions I encountered but I still can't get it to trigger.

I created a queue and a service in the database and I am using a SQL Server account that has all the required permissions as far as I can tell (Connect, Control, Create Procedure, Create Queue, Create Service, Execute, and Subscribe Query Notifications).

I was stuck for a while on an `InvalidOperationException` when I was using this line to create the dependency:

```
// create the SQL dependency
sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
```

`SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.'

I added the options and timeout parameters and that exception stopped occurring but I am not sure it actually fixed the underlying issue.

This is the new line:

```
// create the SQL dependency
sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command, "service=RequestUpdateNotifications;", 0);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1670

Using the SQL Server Profiler I can see the call to the stored procedure (`GetCurrentRequests`) is getting called by '.NET SqlClient Data Provider' (`exec GetCurrentRequests`) and after the timeout another procedure is called by 'RequestUpdateMessages' (`exec sp_executesql N'WAITFOR(RECEIVE TOP (1) message_type_name, conversation_handle, cast(message_body AS XML) as message_body from [RequestUpdateMessages]), TIMEOUT @p2;',N'@p2 int',@p2=60000`)

My issue is that I can't get `OnDependencyChange()` to fire. I have tried using my app to change the values in the table with a stored procedure and tried using SSMS to insert/update values to no avail. Hopefully I missed something simple but I have been googling and tweaking for a few hours and I can't  get it working.

C#

```
internal DatabaseComms(string databaseIp, string databaseName)
{
    connectionString = "Password=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;InitiaCatalog="
        + databaseName + ";Data Source=" + databaseIp + ";";

    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, "RequestUpdateMessages");

    using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Setup the SQL Command
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCurrentRequests", sql);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // create the SQL dependency
        sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command, "service=RequestUpdateNotifications;", 0);

        // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
        sqlDependency.OnChange += new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

        // execute the command
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Close();

        // Dispose of the command
        command.Dispose();
    }
}

void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE ServiceHub SET ENABLE_BROKER;

CREATE QUEUE RequestUpdateMessages;  

CREATE SERVICE RequestUpdateNotifications  
  ON QUEUE RequestUpdateMessages;
```

Comment: Make sure you have the latest ole driver : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @jdweng My drivers were out of date but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: It's a **dependency** - not a "dependancy" ... (all "e" - no "a")

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, I usually just spell it as SQLDep[TAB]